# verifica se o valor do input mudou com jQuery

Tags: jquery

Preciso identificar se o valor de um `input` mudou com o jQuery. Estou tentando fazer assim:

```
$('input[name=cliente]').on('keyup', function(e) {
  // Aqui vou por minhas funções
 }
```

Mas não esta dando certo. Meu `input` tem o nome de `cliente`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu costumo costumo colocar em uma variavel "fora", e "dentro" do evento eu verifico ela.

```
var textoCliente = '';
$('input[name=cliente]').on('keyup', function(e) {
    var textoAtualizado = $(this).val();
    if( textoAtualizado != textoCliente ){
        // Aqui vou por minhas funções
    }
    textoCliente = textoAtualizado;
}
```